# Facebook open graph, filtering friends list array

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want my application to filter the friends list I get using the open graph. People who login into my site must see only their friends who also use my app. I've noticed this on many applications like Quora, Thumb etc. How can it be done using php?

Comment: What have you tried so far in achieving this? Do you have a running example, code, plans or anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can easily be done when you use FQL to query the [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) table (in conjunction with the [`friend`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/) table) – that has a field `is_app_user`, so a query like

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me())
AND is_app_user
```

will return only those friends of the current user that are also users of your app.

Comment: That is pretty awesome, i have been batching graph api calls in a 2 part process to get lists, memebers and exclude non users.  this call does it all in one.  Thank you @cbroe

Answer (score 1):

You can access the lists of a user by access the friendslist connection via graph api

example: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriendlists

```
/me/friendlists?access_token='.$access_token.'
```