# How to find only facebook app installed friends?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am using an app on facebook, I want to find out list which includes only friends who installed same app in there facebook rather than the whole friend list. I am using graph api call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11810543/1427878

Comment: yes I have tried it.. but if we use it,it needs access token of user which gets expired within 2 hours.. do we have any other option than FQL?

Comment: You can get the user’s friendlist via API and do the filtering yourself – but that will need a user access token as well. What’s the problem with just grabbing that info once a user logs in?

Comment: problem is not to grab the detail of user, I want list of friends who installed particular app i.e installed:true only for particular app.. and for this access token of user is not required.. we can do this by access token of app

Comment: No, it does not work with an app access token, even if in `WHERE uid2 = me()` me() gets replaced by actual user id – Graph API Explorer still says this needs a user access token. So, this is the only way to get that info – take it or leave it …

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making a Graph API call to:

```
me/friends?fields=installed,name
```

This will give you the entire list of friends for the current user, however, it will include an additional field called `installed`. If this is set to true, it means the friend has installed the app. You'll have to go through the list and filter out anyone who has `"installed": true`

Alternatively, you can use the following FQL query:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
AND is_app_user = 1
```

Comment: As of FB API v2.0, ONLY friends who have installed the app are ever returned.