# "fields=installed" Responding all my friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently working on an application using the JS Facebook API, (which is currently not public, might be relevant), we are supposed to be 2 people using the application.

I want to get all my friends which are using the application, but when I do :

```
FB.api('me/friends?fields=installed,name,id',function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

or :

```
FB.api('me/friends', { fields: 'id, installed'},function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

It return all my friends.
Do you know why?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785093/facebook-friends-getappusers-using-graph-api). It says that the query returns all friends. However, with the additional field `installed:true` for those friends who use the application. This means, if a particular entry is missing this additional field, that user is not using you Application.

The result will look something like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "{UID1}"
      "name": "{name1}"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "{UID2}"
      "name": "{name2}"
    }, 
    .
    . 
    .
    {
      "installed": true, 
      "id": "{UIDN}"
      "name": "{nameN}"
    }
}
```

Therefore, you can simply check the presence of *installed:true* in the result to find out which all users in the list are using your application.

Source: [Replacement for old GetAppUsers call to see a user's friends who use my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956639/replacement-for-old-getappusers-call-to-see-a-users-friends-who-use-my-applicat)

Comment: Thank you! It actually seems obvious.

Answer (score 0):

are you missing the first `/`?

try :

```
FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'id, installed'}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

This post also might help:

[How to find only facebook app installed friends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832735/how-to-find-only-facebook-app-installed-friends)

Comment: Yes I was, but I think it is useless, or I'm always missing it.
But it didn't change anything, I still get all of my friends.